# wordpress get image caption with wp_get_attachment_image()

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to add the image caption to the `alt` attribute of images in a gallery but my code doesn't work. Below is part of the gallery shortcode modified to implement a slideshow. On the bottom I am using `wp_get_attachment_image()` with `$default_attr` as the array of attributes containing the caption. The caption does not show in HTML.

```
$id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }
   $i = 0;


   $default_attr = array(
    'src'   => $src,
    'class' => "attachment-$size",
    'alt' => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt ))
    );

foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    <a href='".wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID)."'>".wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, $size, false, $default_attr)."</a>      
}     

return $output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->post_title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Came through this while searching for the same answer, found it and wanted to share it:

```
$attachment=get_post($attachment_id);
$alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
$image_title = $attachment->post_title;
$caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
$description = $image->post_content;
```

to output your caption formatted by wordpress (adding breaks and paragraphs) you can just use:

```
$caption = apply_filters('the_content', $caption);
```